# Model validation values in custom Django form error messages

Tags: validation, django-forms

I have created a Django form:

```
class AddFaceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Face
        fields = ('person', 'x', 'y', 'w', 'h')
```

In the `Face` model, `w` is defined as

```
w = models.DecimalField(
    'Relative width',
    validators=[MinValueValidator(0.05), MaxValueValidator(1)]
)
```

If a user enters 0 for the width, the error message Django returns upon form validation is

> Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0.05.

So it nicely contains the value from the `MinValueValidator`. I would like to change it to "Relative width must be >= 0.05".

To achieve it, I tried customising errors in AddFaceForm Meta

```
class AddFaceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Face
        fields = ('person', 'x', 'y', 'w', 'h')
        error_messages = {
            'w': {
                'min_value': 'Relative width must be >= 0.05'
            }
        }
```

But this means hard-coding the 0.05 value. I would like to read it from the model definition. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.

[MinValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/core/validators/#MinValueValidator) is a subclass of [BaseValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/core/validators/#BaseValidator). And, `BaseValidator` takes an optional message in its constructor. From the [code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/core/validators/#BaseValidator) you can see that the message can use the following three parameters: `limit_value`, `show_value` and `value`. `limit_value` is the minimum value for the validator which is `0.05` in this case. `show_value` is the cleaned value the user enters and `value` is the raw value they enter. Hence, you can do the following to achieve your goal:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Face(models.Model):
    w = models.DecimalField(
        'Relative width',
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.05, _('Relative width must be >= %(limit_value)s'))],
    )
```

Alternatively, if you'd rather specify the error message in a form then you can do the following:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import Face


class FaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Face
        fields = ['w']
        error_messages = {
            'w': {
                'min_value': _('Relative width must be >= %(limit_value)s')
            }
        }
```

The [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield) docs tell you that you can interpolate `limit_value`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a working solution. However doesn't it mix the model layer (limit definition) with the representation layer (error message text)? I would prefer to define the error text separately, where I am defining how my site interacts with the user (i.e. in the views and templates). Is it possible to access the limit_value outside the validation definition? Anything like w.validators[0].limit_value?

Comment: That's a great point. I'll update my answer with my recent findings.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot.